# Azure Blob Container Logging

Tags: azure, logging, blob, storage

Do azure provide seperate logging options on per-container basis? I could not find it?

Or is there any way to list logs of a particular container in azure?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by logging options? Please update your question with these details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no logging option on a per-container basis. You can however pull the data from the storage logs corresponding to a particular container.

Here is an article which talks about what is logged in the Storage container:
[Azure Storage Logging: Using Logs to Track Storage Requests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/08/02/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests/)

You can use the "**Request URL**" field. It contains the full URL that is received by the service.

> Example: `"PUT http://kaushal.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?comp=block&Id="`

This field will contain your **container** name, so you can write queries to filter on this.